# Problem 81 of Hardy and Williams' "Green Book"

Tags: real-analysis

The "Green Book of Mathematical Problems" by Kenneth Hardy and Kenneth S. Williams, which I used to revere as an undergraduate, gives the following problem #81:

> Let $f(x)$ be an integrable function on the closed interval $[\pi/2,\pi]$ and suppose that $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi f(x) \sin kx\ d x = \left\{\begin{array}{cc}0,& 1\leq k \leq n-1, \\ 1,& k=n . \end{array}\right.$
>
> Prove that $|f(x)| \geq {1 \over \pi \ln 2}$ on a set of positive measure.

I am curious to know what bound one can derive, by only considering the $k=n$ constraint on the integral, and ignoring the other constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question because I was worried that my answer was wrong, and I wanted to see if anyone else would come up with the same answer. I guess I could have made the question sound more interesting. Problem 81 is what I saw when I decided to do a math problem for the first time in two years - I opened the Green Book randomly to this page. I was surprised when I found that I could do the problem in my head, and get a better bound than the one in the book, even though the solution in the book uses obscure trigonometric identities and takes two pages.

My solution was to start with the $k=n$ constraint, as I noted in the original question above. Given the bound $|f(x)|\leq a$, the $f$ which maximizes the integral should consist of a square wave alternating between $\pm a$ (to always make a positive product with $\sin kx$). By duality, if the integral is fixed to have the value $1$ then the $f$ with smallest range should have this form as well. For a square wave, the integral is $a$ times the area under $|\sin kx|$ between $\pi/2$ and $\pi$, which is the same for all integer $k$, as can be understood visually (it is just the "density" of the waveform times $\pi/2$). Evaluating at e.g. $k=1$ we see that this area is 1, so the integral is just $a$. The integral being constrained to 1 gives us $a=1$ as the smallest possible range for $f$; we conclude that a contradiction arises if $f(x)<1$ everywhere, so we must have $f(x)\geq 1$ on a set of positive measure. This is a better bound than the book's ${1 \over \pi \log 2}\approx 0.459$. It will of course continue to hold when the other constraints are included. Am I making a mistake, or did Hardy and Williams miss something?